# Присвоить новый класс ссылке при переходе по ней

Tags: php, javascript

Есть меню из трех пунктов:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/zhenschinam/">Женщинам</a></span>
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/muzhchinamm/">Мужчинам</a></span>
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/detjamd/">Детям</a></span>
</div>
```

```css
.activelink {
  color: #222;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Мне нужно реализовать подчеркивание пункта меню при переходе по нем, как это сделано на https://lamoda.ru/ .

Подсказали, что это можно сделать с помощью php - но, к сожалению, я не силен в синтаксисе.

Сейчас реализовано через js - но по ссылке перейти нельзя: https://bigcitymart.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('topmenulink');

for (var i=0; i < elem.length; i++) {

  elem[i].addEventListener('click', activelink)
}

function activelink (e) {

  if (document.getElementsByClassName('activelink')[0]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('activelink')[0].classList.remove('activelink')
  }

  e.target.className += ' activelink';
}
```

```css
.activelink {
  color: #222;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="#">Женщинам</a></span>
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="#">Мужчинам</a></span>
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="#">Детям</a></span>
</div>
```

На `php` можно глянуть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963757/how-to-set-current-page-active-in-php).