# Сохранение активной ссылки

Tags: php, javascript

Есть меню категорий. При нажатии на определённую категорию нужно, чтобы ссылка стала активной и исчез атрибут href. А так же при переходе на другую страницу (например, страница 2, то есть есть постраничная навигация для текущей категории), эта же ссылка также сохраняла свою актвиность, пока не переключусь на другую категорию.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696846

Comment: Не особо понятно что вы хотите сделать

Comment: я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку меню, эта ссылка была активной, то есть выделялась каким-то цветом, а так же при нажатии на номер страницы, чтобы ссылка эта же не теряла свою активность, то есть сохраняла цвет

Answer (score 0):

Я там понимаю, что при клике на номер страницы происходит переход на эту страницу. То есть надо где-то сохранить данные о том, что пользователь выбрал какую-то категорию и получить эту информацию на новой странице.

Предлагаю сохранять данные о выбранных категориях в $_SESSION при помощи ajax запроса при клике на категорию, а на новой странице из $_SESSION получать эту информацию и отображать ее.